# Display names in Django admin deployed on heroku

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have deployed a django app on heroku. If i visit /admin of my app and login, 
[image: 1]]

I am getting Category object displayed here instead of the actual name of the category, though I have mentioned it in models.py.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    sales_price = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have added those category objects through the admin interface itself. Might this have anything to do with the display?

Comment: `__str__` method is the one to override. See here for more information about how django admin site uses it for readable object names. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure you are running the same version of Python in development as in Heroku.

Here you are obviously using Python 3, so you should define `__str__` in your model class instead of `__unicode__`.

Answer (score 0):

Python2:

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return self.name
```

Python3 :The **str**() method is called whenever you call str() on an object. In Python 3, Django uses str(obj) in a number of places [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#unicode)
for one:

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

for multiple:

```
def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to define an admin class in your admin.py file like this:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name',)
```

And register it:

```
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

See [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: Sorry miss clicked the post button too fast.

Comment: Can we see the relevant parts of your admin.py file then? That's where you define what appears on the admin page.

Comment: I resolved it. Had to use __str__. Error with python version! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad that it's solved :) Still consider using a proper admin file if you want to things right and allow more columns to be display for your models.

Comment: Okay, will do that.